# Why do my pivot tables sometimes lose their bottom border?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

In Excel I've made a number of pivot tables in order to display text information for users (I've had to block out a lot of the information in the image below!)

I have a macro that changes the filter to a certain user for all of these, however, for each different user, at least one of these pivot tables seems to lose the styling for the bottom border and the only correlation I can find is when there are two rows in the pivot table. The example below shows that two of them at the bottom have no bottom border, however, when you change the filter to another user this could be one or more different tables. There is no hidden cell below these, they all use the same pivot style and all have "preserve cell formatting on update" selected.

Why is this only happening when there are two rows in the pivot table?

[image: Pivottables]

Comment: I am not able to replicate the problem. A few questions: 1) What version of Excel? 2) Which pivot style? 3) Since you are using VBA, have you tried re-applying the style after applying the filter?

Comment: 1) I'm using Microsoft Office 2016, although this was happening in the previous version before upgrading. 2) Pivot style Dark 11 3) Tried to change and mess about with the styles a few times, just always happens when there is two rows in each pivot table. The only other thing I can say is that I have text wrapping on.

Comment: Sorry - still not able to replicate the problem.